# Writing constantly Data into a File

Tags: c#, file, oop

My Program ist getting alot and very frequently Data, up to 2-4 Times per second. My Goal is to take this Data and write it into a File.
My Question now, is it smart to having a File-Pointer constantly open? May it be better to just cache the Data first and then write it into a File?
How is the perfomance?

Are there Design-Patterns which are good for this? Any Tips are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually buffering is already implemented in standard System.IO.FileStream http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx
Instead of constant writing all changes are accumulated in buffer and flush to disk as buffer getting full. Just remember specify buffer in constructor and call flush as you finish.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically flush after a period of time ?

Comment: It will flush as you close stream, but as far as I know System.IO one can not autoflush by timer, but you may implement it on your own using System.Timers.Timer to call flush after interval elapsed and restart timer on each new write.